# Error when deployed the rails app with webpack in the Heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack

I don't really understand the webpack assets loading order.

I created JavaScript files like this.

```
// app/javascript/packs/foo.js
import somelibrary;
function someFunction() {
    // ...
}

<!-- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb -->
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'foo' %>
```

This works fine in localhost, but when I deployed it to the Heroku, this caused the compile error which said that `Could not find somelibrary` (sorry, I lost the precise error message).

And I tried this instead of above one, it works both in local host and Heroku.

```
// app/javascript/components/foo.js
import somelibrary;
function someFunction() {
    // ...
}
export { someFunction };

// app/javascript/packs/application.js
import { someFunction } from '../components/foo.js';
someFunction();

<!-- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb -->
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack will try to create a "pack" for every javascript or similar file found inside `app/javascript/packs`, i.e. files you could require using `javascript_pack_tag`.

So in this context, `app/javascript/packs/foo.js` is compiled alone and will have to resolve `import somelibrary;` by itself, whereas `app/javascript/components/foo.js` is compiled as part of `app/javascript/packs/application.js` (where it's required) and somehow has a way of loading your library.

You could try manually building the assets to see all the packs generated by webpack, and detect compilation errors before deploying, or simply put all your components and other source files in another folder than `app/javascript/packs`.

Comment: Thank you for your the answer! So why did compiling `packs/foo.js` alonely fail?

Comment: I don't know precisely, you did not give the error message, but there could be many reason, like your library being made accessible by some other code in application.js so the import works in this case but not if you're trying to compile foo.js alone